# Use UriBuilder and construct httpRequest

Tags: c#, uri, httprequest, uribuilder

I try to build the following uri

```
http://localhost:8080/TestService.svc/RunTest
```

I do it as  following

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
uriBuilder.Host = "localhost:8080/TestService.svc";
uriBuilder.Path = String.Format("/{0}", "RunTest");
string address = uriBuilder.ToString()

//In debugger the address looks like http://[http://localhost:8080/TestService.svc]/RunTest
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(address);
```

The above generates an exception

```
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

I`ll appreciate your help in solving the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the Uri builder you need to put the host, port & path as it's own line.   Also TestService.svc is also part of the path and not the host, you can get away with it if not using port but with port they have to be separated out.

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
uriBuilder.Host = "localhost";
uriBuilder.Port = 8080;
uriBuilder.Path = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", "TestService.svc", "RunTest");
var address = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I also see square brackets as the value for the `address` variable as you point out, but I don't see `PerfTestService` in the generated Uri, nor do I see why this would be?! I see:

```
http://[localhost:8080/TestService.svc]/RunTest
```

Since you already know the host and the path, I suggest you construct it as a string.

```
 var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/TestService.svc/RunTest");
 string address = uriBuilder.ToString();
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```